# postgresql NOT ILIKE clause does not include null string values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's the setup on Postgresql 9.2.4:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    some_text text
);
```

Now we enter one record, with a null or empty string for `some_text`, so that when we query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_text IS NULL;
```

I get the entry back. So far so good.

However, when I query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_text NOT ILIKE "%anything%';
```

I find that nothing was returned. Why is that? I expect a null or empty string to be "not like `anything`".

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In SQL, NULL is not equal to anything.  Nor is it unequal to anything.

In other words, if I don't tell you my middle name, and you don't tell me your middle name, how can we know if our two middle names are the same name or different names?  We can't know.

This often trips people up in SQL, because it's "tri-value logic."  An expression can be TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN.  Those of us familiar with boolean algebra know that NOT TRUE is FALSE, and NOT FALSE is TRUE.

But the tricky part is that NOT UNKNOWN is still UNKNOWN.

So the solution for you is either always store a non-null string in your column, or else use an expression to account for tri-value logic:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_text NOT ILIKE "%anything%' OR some_text IS NULL;
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE COALESCE(some_text, '') NOT ILIKE '%anything%';
```

PostgreSQL also supports a [null-safe equality operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-comparison.html):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_text IS DISTINCT FROM 'anything';
```

But unfortunately, this works only for equality, not for LIKE/ILIKE with patterns and wildcards.

Comment: I like you're explanation with *unknowns*, but I'm not sure how that connects the the SQL. Why is a `WHERE null ILIKE '%anything%'` unknown?

Comment: "Young man, in mathematics you don't understand things. You just get used to them." -- John von Neumann

Comment: oooh the sass. Is that a hard follow-up question?

Comment: @applepie: May seem cocky to disagree with von Neumann, but this is actually easy to understand IMO. Imagine a black box. You don't know what's in it. The content is *unknown*. If you ask whether the content is like `%anything%`, you cannot be sure. The answer is *unknown* as well ...

Comment: ahh thanks Erwin. I knew what you said already, but I was confused as to why `null == unknown`. If `null` is not equal or unequal to anything, then it makes sense that it's `unknown`.

Answer (score 9):

You may use COALESCE to achieve your goal, like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE COALESCE(some_text,'') NOT ILIKE "%anything%';
```

Comment: You're assuming `anything` isn't an empty string. If it is this query will return no rows.