# PostgreSQL: "select where" query filtering out records with [null] values

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I run the following simple query:

```sql
SELECT gateway, customer_id
FROM gateways
where gateway = '1000056'
```

Here's the record it returns, showing a [null] customer ID:

[image: PostgreSQL record showing null customer_id]

When I add another filter, the record is no longer returned, but I think it ***SHOULD STILL*** be returned since the `customer_id` is *not equal to* 21 :

```sql
SELECT gateway, customer_id
FROM gateways
where gateway = '1000056'
    and customer_id != 21 --new filter!
```

The record is no longer returned:

[image: record no longer return; zero records returned]

How can I filter out records whose `customer_id` = 21, but still return this record where `customer_id` = [null]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243755/postgresql-not-ilike-clause-does-not-include-null-string-values). Here's a direct quote from that answer:

> In SQL, NULL is not equal to anything. Nor is it unequal to anything.
>
> In other words, if I don't tell you my middle name, and you don't tell
> me your middle name, how can we know if our two middle names are the
> same name or different names? We can't know.
>
> This often trips people up in SQL, because it's "tri-value logic." An
> expression can be TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN. Those of us familiar with
> boolean algebra know that NOT TRUE is FALSE, and NOT FALSE is TRUE.
>
> But the tricky part is that NOT UNKNOWN is still UNKNOWN.
>
> So the solution for you is either always store a non-null string in
> your column, or else use an expression to account for tri-value logic

This works:

```sql
SELECT gateway, customer_id
FROM gateways
where gateway = '1000056'
    and customer_id is distinct from 21
```

Returning the record I want:
[image: the record I want to be returned]

Comment: To "always store a non-null string" instead of NULL is a bad idea. Null has a purpose!